# How do I create Fortify Alchemy enchantments up to 29%? 

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was making a set of Fortify Alchemy to 29% to be able to create stronger enchantments. For some reason my Fortify Alchemy gear only goes to a maximum of 23% and I've read/seen people creating enchantments with a 29% bonus.

I have 100 Alchemy skill and 100 Enchantment skill with all the necessary perks.

I was trying to do this: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Enchanting_(Skyrim)#Exploit

Comment: I have the same problem, with all the perks and all lvl 100 skills needed my first potion gives only 27% fortify enchanting - the gears 20% fortify alchemy - the second gear 22% and the next potion 28% fortify enchanting - now the number does not increase - gear 22% and potion 28%.

Answer (score 13):

You can raise your Enchantment skill above 100, by using potions that increase your Enchantment skill.

To get the maximum possible enchantments you need to raise your Alchemy skill to the highest level. You can create Fortify Alchemy enchantments that will increase the effect of your potions considerably.

So you should first create a set of Apparel that gives you the highest possible bonus you can currently achieve to Alchemy. Use that set to create a batch of Fortify Enchanting potions. Now your enchantments should be stronger when you use the potions just before enchanting your gear.

You will have to do a few rounds of enchanting and creating potions if you're after the maximally possible effect. So, use your enchanted alchemy gear to create an enchanting potion. Then use that potion to create better Fortify Alchemy gear. Now you can use that improved gear to create a better enchanting potion, repeat until no more improvement is visible.

There are diminishing returns, so you won't be able to increase your stats infinitely.

Comment: the problem is my enchants are coming lower than it should, with the first use of fortify ench potion the gear of fort alch should be 26%, i can only get 21% on those

Comment: @shandow do you have the appropriate enchanting perks? 100% better enchantments, and +25% on fortify skill perks?

Comment: i have enchanter 5/5, insightful enchanter, curpus enchanter and extra effect.

Comment: Are you possible to get this effect without having 5/5 enchanting? What if you just make more potion rounds? Like instead of 3 alchemy clothing, you make even more?

Comment: no its not possible to get the max effect without investing all the perks

Answer (score 10):

The trick is to do multiple loops of Fortify Alchemy/Enchanting

You will need some cheap clothing for this.

Important is to have 100 Alchemy, 100 Enchanting, and (optional) 100 Smithing.

You will need at least the following Perks:

- Alchemist 5/5 (Alchemy)
- Enchanter 5/5 (Enchanting)
- Insightful Enchanter (Enchanting)
- **(Optional)** Extra Effect (Enchanting)
- **(Optional)** Armor of your choice (Smithing)

---

1. Create a 4 pieces of Fortify Alchemy Equipment (hat, gloves, necklace, ring)
2. With the clothing on, create some (4) Fortify Enchanting Potions
3. Create a new, stronger set of Fortify Alchemy Clothing by drinking those potions.
4. With the Stronger Set, Create some new Fortify Enchanting Potions (they're stronger as the previous ones.)
5. Now you'll create your Final set of Fortify Achemy Equipment (hat, gloves, necklace, ring) under influence of those stronger potions.
6. You now can use this Fortify Achemy set to create as many Fortify Enchanting Potions as you need to improve your other stuff.
7. **(Optional)** Create some Fortify Smithing Potions, and some (4) Fortify Enchanting Potions (obviously, while wearing your Final set of Fortify Alchemy Equipment)
8. **(Optional)** Create a set of Fortify Smithing Equipment (armour, gloves, necklace, ring)
9. **(Optional)** Improving weapons while under the influence of those Fortify Smithing Potions while wearing Fortify Smithing Equipment allows you to create the strongest weapons in the game.

Comment: The fastest way to level up Alchemy is to make potions that have the most value, for example Invisibility potions. When playing the game and leveling your toon, you pick up all ingredients you come across everywhere and store them some place until the day you make potions. Then just create tons of pots with high value wearing a full +alchemy gear set. Similarly for blacksmithing you can improve e.g. glass or ebony gear that you have improved perk in while wearing +blacksmith gear. Blacksmithing will level up very fast then.

Comment: In the beginning btw you can pick up all leather gear too and improve those to level blacksmithing faster in the start - although later you will have to do it for higher quality gear.

Answer (score 5):

Wear a falmer helmet and a circlet at the same time. This gives you five slots for fortify alchemy instead of four. I believe it maxes out being able to make potions that give +37% Enchanting for 30 Seconds. That's when you're wearing five +29% bonuses to alchemy and make the potion. I do not think you can go higher, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The Smart guy here is the one who just told me about wearing the falmer helment and a circlet at the same time (thanks, couldnt get past 29%). everything else is commen sense mathmatically speaking. if u want to be a beast u want smithing, enchanting, and alchemy. use those bad boys and u will rule on master difficulty (assuming u got heavy armor and a very high magicka resistance). spend points in sneak if u want tha one hitter quitter. FYI: dagger perk is useless sword surpasses it in the end.

Answer (score 1):

The glitch that may be causing the problem concerns equipping the fortify alchemy equipment.

If you have 100 in alchemy and 100 in enchanting, 5/5, and the perks, then you should be able to begin with creating 25% fortify alchemy gear. If you can't, then check your magical effects before beginning. If they all are not in effect, try unequipping and re-equipping your fortify alchemy gear. There appears to be a glitch and sometimes the effects are not properly activated. The unequipping and re-equipping of the gear seems to correct the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. Generally, 100 enchantment with 5/5 first perk and improved fortifies should give +25% alchemy with a grand soul without any potions. If in your version it only gives 21-23, you need to update your game.