# How do I create a Fortify Enchantment potion up to +32%?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How do I create a fortify enchantement potion up to 32%? I've read this chart http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=20366 and I wonder how is this possible? I've 5 fortify alchemy items (falmer helmet + circlet exploit) all around +21 percent and my alchemy skill is at lvl 60 but my highest potion is up to +21 percent. When I remove a fortify alchemy item I get up to +20 enchantement potion loosing just +1 percent? Is there a fortify alchemy potion I can swallow? It's seems a bit high? My enchantment skill is lvl 70. I've additionaly two fortify one-handed items up to +33 percent each but my damage is up to +120 only? I've read this [How do I create Fortify Alchemy enchantments up to 29%?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39923/how-do-i-create-fortify-alchemy-enchantments-up-to-29)  maybe it is a bug?

Comment: Bit late in the day for me to write a full answer up, so here's a quicky. "damage is up to +120", I believe a high smithing adds more damage than fortify n-handed enchantments. Enchanting is used to make the +smith equipment and +alch equipment (which in turn gives more +smith).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to maximize the strength of your potions, make sure you have all alchemy and enchanting related perks and 100 in alchemy and enchanting.

They even mention this in the source you link:

> Level 100 Alchemy (5 X Alchemy, Physician, Benefactor: 7 Perks)

Comment: @desaivv: 5x Alchemy means the root of the skill tree is multiply with 5. Physicisn and Benefactor are edges of the tree.

Comment: It refers to the 5 alchemy perks that (total) give +100% alchemy, and the physician (prereq) and benefactor (+25% beneficial potions) perks.

Comment: @Toast: When you have 1x alchemy and all the other perks you have a total of +20 percent alchemy boost?

Comment: @Toast: Do you mean you have +150% boost? The link is deleted.

Comment: You end up with +125% (100% for 5 perks in Alchemist, 25% for 1 perk in benefactor).  Here's a better link: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alchemy

Answer (score 1):

Spoiler follows:

> Create a fortify restoration potion and drink it while the alchemy items are equipped.  Immediately after drinking it (before exiting the items menu) remove all of the alchemy items, exit out of all the menus and then go back in and re-equip them (the alchemy items).  Quickly go back in and create a new restoration potion which should be stronger than the first.  Follow the same: drink, take items off, exit menu, put items back on -> create new restoration potion a couple more times.  When you're satisfied, do the same as before but this time create an enchantment potion.  You might have only 60 seconds to complete the process before the original restoration wears off but it only takes a few cycles to get very powerful results.  The same can be done with fortify smithing.  You could ultimately create weapons with millions of damage points if you wanted to go that far.  I found that it makes the game much less enjoyable and rather use regular weapons/armor etc.

One thing I used this for that I don't consider 'cheating' is to

> create a fortify alteration potion with a high percentage:  spells last 20,000% longer for 60 secs etc.  Then you drink that and cast the candlelight spell and it lasts much longer while in the dark.  You can also drink the enhanced restoration potion with amulet of talos unequipped, equip the item and wait for a day or two.  That will remove the wait time between shouts.

Comment: My potions are about +120% Smithing and +30% Enchanting. My crafting gear is+29% X 4 and my Armor value is about 1200. I wonder when I get +2400 AR?