# Trying to get 29% fortify destruction

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have ALL the perks for enchanting (100) ALL the perks for smithing (100) and all the perks for destruction (100 again) yet I can only enchant my daedric helmet with fortify destruction to 15%.  I want to do the thing where you can get 100% fortify destruction if you doi it on four peices of apparel, however I don't know what I am doing wrong :(

Comment: I can't see anything there that will answer my question @z-

Comment: sorry, wrong link: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39923/how-do-i-create-fortify-alchemy-enchantments-up-to-29